# How to play a video in background using YTPlayer in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ytplayerview

I am getting the following error message...

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[YTPlayerView playerView]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd77bd41f80'

and here is my code..

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification
{   
    [_playerView performSelector:@selector(playerView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

}

- (IBAction)didTapPlayPause:(id)sender {
    self.btnPlayPause.selected = !self.btnPlayPause.selected;
    if (self.btnPlayPause.selected)
    {
        self.title=self.strngvideotitle;
        self.playerView=[[YTPlayerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,375,290)];
        [self.playerView loadWithVideoId:self.strngvideoId];
        [self.view addSubview:_playerView];

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

   }
```

Comment: show your `@selector(playerView)` code

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik....I changed it but still showing the same error message

Comment: change this `[_playerView performSelector:@selector(playerView)` into `[self performSelector:@selector(playerView)` and try once

Comment: @Roby Anbu asked for the code of `playerView` method, which may be like `-(void)playerView{};`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik....I tried..still the same error message...

Comment: @Roby - can you show your `playerView` this method where you created

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails at this statement

```
[_playerView performSelector:@selector(playerView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

The statement expects that your `_playerView` object will call the method `playerView` after a delay of 0.1 seconds. But the class `YTPlayerView` does not have a method called `playerView`. You might want to check the actual method name and replace it in the selector name.

Comment: ya may be correct, allocate your `self.playerView=[[YTPlayerView alloc]` in didfinish launch o

Comment: That is not the point. The problem is that there is no method called `playerView`. The method would be called something else like `playVideo` maybe (https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/blob/master/Classes/YTPlayerView.h#L247)